# data.table list .N (count) removes row completely rather than imputing 0 count

Tags: r, list, count, data.table

Say I have this data.table:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                 Flag = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1))
df <- data.table(df)

df
   ID Flag
1:  A    1
2:  A    1
3:  A    1
4:  A    1
5:  B    0
6:  B    0
7:  B    0
8:  B    1
```

and I wish to count the number of 0 and 1 flags for each ID, as such:

```
Summary <- df[, list(Count = .N), by = c("ID","Flag")]
```

this returns the following results:

```
Summary
   ID Flag Count
1:  A    1     4
2:  B    0     3
3:  B    1     1
```

So, since there are no 0's recorded against ID A, there is no row which lists the combination of ID A and Flag 0, with a count of zero.

What would be the way to do this using data.table?

I.e.. I want to achieve this result:

```
Summary
  ID Flag Count
1  A    0     0
2  A    1     4
3  B    0     3
4  B    1     1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could factor the column, then tabulate.  Since we know we only want 0 and 1 levels, we can just use `0:1` for the `Flag` column and not need to actually assign the `Flag` column as a factor.  Although this method would be slower (see second part).

```
df[, .(Flag = 0:1, Count = tabulate(factor(Flag, levels = 0:1))), by = ID]
#    ID Flag Count
# 1:  A    0     0
# 2:  A    1     4
# 3:  B    0     3
# 4:  B    1     1
```

As thelatemail notes in the comments, a faster method would be to factor the whole column first, then tabulate based on `ID`.

```
df[, Flag := factor(Flag, levels = 0:1)]
df[, .(Flag = levels(Flag), Count = tabulate(Flag)), by = ID]
#    ID Flag Count
# 1:  A    0     0
# 2:  A    1     4
# 3:  B    0     3
# 4:  B    1     1
```

Comment: My query I suppose is if the use of `tabulate` is going to bog down the speed of `data.table` which `by=` would otherwise provide. But it is very clever, no doubt! :-)

Comment: Strangely enough, this is pretty quick, but only after removing the `factor()` call from inside each `by=` group. Do the `factor` conversion once for the whole data.table and it is very quick to tabulate then.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Makes an order of magnitude difference when dealing with 1/2 a million ID's. A join is probably still faster for very large data I would have thought, but this isn't too shabby at all.